# Given a number, how to render multiple html element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I would like to pass props `noOfIcons` to my ChartLegend component and if there is noOfIcons value then I would like to render the given number of icons. So if noOfIcons = 2 then render 2 `<Icon/>`. I've tried the following but it always renders only 1 `<Icon/>`, What am I missing? & if there is a simple way to handle this please suggest. Many thanks.

```
 <ChartLegend iconName={"square-full"} noOfIcons={2} label={'label'} />
```

```
const ChartLegend = props => {

    const { iconName, label, noOfIcons = 2 } = props;

    const renderIcons = () => {

        if (!noOfIcons) {
            return <Icon
                name={iconName}
                type='solid'
            />;
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < noOfIcons; i++) {
                return <Icon
                    name={iconName}
                    type='solid'
                />;
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <Col> 
            {renderIcons()} 
            {label}
        </Col>
    );
};

export default ChartLegend;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array map method for rendering multiple icons.

Usually, when you use react to render multiple components of the same type you use the map method.

```
const ChartLegend = props => {

    const { iconName, label, noOfIcons = 2 } = props;

    const renderIcons = () => {

        if (!noOfIcons) {
            return <Icon
                name={iconName}
                type='solid'
            />;
        }
        else {
            Array(noOfIcons)
                .fill(0)
                .map((v,i) =>{
                   return <Icon
                       key={i}
                       name={iconName}
                       type='solid'
                   />;
           })
        }
    };

    return (
        <Col> 
            {renderIcons()} 
            {label}
        </Col>
    );
};

export default ChartLegend;
```

This will be a shorter and more readable (in my opinion) way for doing so:

```
    const renderIcons = () => {
        return(
           Array(noOfIcons? noOfIcons: 1)
               .fill(0)
               .map((v,i) =>{
                   return <Icon
                       key={i}
                       name={iconName}
                       type='solid'
                   />;
           })
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return an array to render multiple elements. So in your else part,

```
{
          const arr = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < noOfIcons; i++) {
                arr.push( <Icon
                    name={iconName}
                    type='solid'
                />);
            }
         return arr;
        }
```

Something like this can work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `n` elements and iterate over it to render the icons elements. If noOfIcons is equal to `0` then create an array of one element:

```
<Col> 
    {[...Array(noOfIcons || 1)].map((_, index) => 
      (<Icon name={iconName} type='solid' key={`solid_icon_${index}`} />))} 
    {label}
</Col>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ChartLegend = props => {

   const { iconName, label, noOfIcons = 2 } = props;

   const renderIcons = () => Array(noOfIcons)
            .fill(0)
            .map(e => (<Icon
                name={iconName}
                type='solid'
            />));
    
  return (
    <Col> 
        {renderIcons()} 
        {label}
    </Col>
   );
};

export default ChartLegend;
```

use `Array.map`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use map.

Replace this

```
for (let i = 0; i < noOfIcons; i++) {
                return <Icon
                    name={iconName}
                    type='solid'
                />;
            }
```

with

```
return noOfIcons.map(()=> (<Icon name={iconName} type='solid' />)
```